# Is webinternetsecurity a threat to a network and how to remove completely?

Tags: windows-7, networking, security, malware

I am in IT and one of our computer was detected to have a trojan virus. It was detected as Artemis!294D8BF17879. It turns out to be an application called WebInternetSecurity that appears to create more ads and pop ups while using a web browser.

Here are two links for more information about the application:
http://www.shouldiremoveit.com/WebInternetSecurity-105455-program.aspx
http://www.pcthreat.com/parasitebyid-41351en.html

It was only detected on one computer. I was wondering if it posed a threat to the network (any malicious code or send/receive data), or if anyone knew more about what it does? And also does removing it via Programs and Features in control panel remove it completely?

The computer itself has windows 7 (64 bit) and uses IE8. Let me know if more information is needed?

Answer (score 1):

Source http://malwaretips.com/blogs/webinternetsecurity-virus-removal/

> WebInternetSecurity is an adware program that is commonly bundled with
> other free programs that you download off of the Internet.
> Unfortunately, some free downloads do not adequately disclose that
> other software will also be installed and you may find that you have
> installed WebInternetSecurity without your knowledge.
>
> WebInternetSecurity is advertised as a program that will protect your
> PC while you browse the Internet. Though this may sound like a useful
> service, the WebInternetSecurity program can be intrusive and will
> display ads whether you want them to or not.
>
> The WebInternetSecurity adware infection is designed specifically to
> make money. It generates web traffic, collects sales leads for other
> dubious sites, and will display advertisements and sponsored links
> within your web browser.
>
> It’s technically not a
> virus, but **it does exhibit plenty of malicious traits, such as rootkit
> capabilities to hook deep into the operating system, browser
> hijacking, and in general just interfering with the user experience.**
> The industry generally refers to it as a “PUP,” or potentially
> unwanted program.
>
> WebInternetSecurity is an ad-supported (users may see additional
> banner, search, pop-up, pop-under, interstitial and in-text link
> advertisements) cross web browser plugin for Internet Explorer,
> Firefox and Chrome, and distributed through various monetization
> platforms during installation.
>
> WebInternetSecurity is typically added
> when you install another free software (video recording/streaming,
> download-managers or PDF creators) that had bundled into their
> installation this adware program. When you install these free
> programs, they will also install WebInternetSecurity as well. Some of
> the programs that are known to bundle WebInternetSecurity include
> “Youtube Downloader HD”, “Fast Free Converter”, “Video Media Player
> 1.1″ and “DVDX Player 3.2″.
>
> When installed, WebInternetSecurity browser extension will display
> advertising banners on the webpages that you are visiting, stating
> that they are brought to you by “Ads by WebInternetSecurity”.
>
> WebInternetSecurity may also display pop-up advertisements, in-text
> ads and as you browse Internet, it will show coupons and other deals
> available on different websites.
>
> Warning, this program is very aggressive adware. **Not only does it
> hijack the user’s browser and settings, it hijacks visited web sites
> by injecting its own advertising over the web sites ads including
> Adsense.**

There is a complete removal guide as well.

**You need to do a lot more than just uninstall from Programs and Features in control panel to remove it completely.**